# Adobe Flash CS5 loses session on every request on Mac

Tags: flash, macos, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I just transferred my project from PC to Mac and the first request is login.
Every other requests require login.

On PC login and session is ok, on Mac in browser everything is ok, but on Mac in FlashPro when I test my swf the session is lost right after first request.
Every request is in new session?!

I found a forum post from Flash CS4 with same issue and the problem is still not fixed.

Is there a workaround or something to do with it.
It is very annoying to publish every time I want to check something.

PS: The server part is on ASP .NET, but I'm sure it's not the problem.

Comment: If someone have the same problem, I'm using publish with preview. It's almost the same.